# Deleting newlines in a Range with sed

Tags: sed

How do I make this:

```
    TextTextText
    start
    stuff
    stuff
    stuff
    end
    start
    stuff
    end
    TextTextText
```

Look like this:

```
    startstuffstuffstuffend
    startstuffend
```

with sed?
I tried this:

```
    sed -e '/start/,/end/N; s/\n//'
```

but it did this:

```
    startstuff
    stuffstuff
    endstart
    stuff
    end
```

It's only every second line...

Comment: Information is insufficient. Are there lines before `start` or after `end`? Is there additional whitespace before or after the text of each line?

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot, I edit EDIT: did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try following command:

```
sed -n '/start/,/end/ H; $ { g; s/\n//g; s/\(end\)/\1\n/g; p }' infile
```

It avoids automatic printing (`-n`), saves all lines between the range `start` and `end` in the hold buffer (`H`), and when the whole file has been processed (`$`), first removes all newlines characters and then adds one after each `end` word.

It yields:

```
startstuffstuffstuffend
startstuffend
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been searching this for two days!

Comment: Actually, when i have more than 2 "start end" ranges it writes them together in 1 line...

Comment: @birei can you look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947391/delete-n-characters-from-line-range-in-text-file answer here works only in range, what to change to preserve outrange lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '/start/ {f=1} f {printf $1} /end/ {f=0;print ""}' file
startstuffstuffstuffend
startstuffend
```

Or you can do

```
awk '/start/,/end/ {printf $1;if ($0~/end/) print ""}' file
startstuffstuffstuffend
startstuffend
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/start/
   {
: again
   N
   s/End$/&/
   t clean
   b again
: clean
   s/\n//g
   }
' file
```

Concatenate also if there is not "End" but only a Start, but maybe you don't want this (problem also occur in other answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/start/{h;:l n;H;/^end$/!bl;x;s/\n//g;p}' input
```