# Delete \n characters from line range in text file

Tags: perl, awk, sed

Let's say we have a text file with 1000 lines.

How can we delete new line characters from line 20 to 500 (replace them with space for example)?

My try:

```
sed '20,500p; N; s/\n/ /;' #better not to say anything
```

All other lines (1-19 && 501-1000) should be preserved as-is.

As I'm familiar with sed, awk or perl solutions are welcomed, but please give an explanation with them as I'm a perl and awk newbie.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed: How can I replace a newline (\n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

Comment: @Evert not too sure about that, the question is about replacing _every_ newline in a file, not just the ones within a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner to strip the newline:

```
perl -i -pe 'chomp if 20..500' file
```

Or to replace it with a space:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\R/ / if 20..500' file
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `chomp`: Remove new line
- `20 .. 500`: if [Range operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) is between line numbers 20 to 500

Comment: Starting good book for perl programming, specially parsing? @miller

Comment: Whether one is an experienced Perl programmer or a beginner, the first resource I'd probably point one to is: [Modern Perl Book by chromatic](http://modernperlbooks.com/).  It teaches one not just how to write Perl, but how to write it well, and is available free online.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this (my example is on a slightly smaller scale :-)

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (2<=NR&&NR<=5?FS:RS)}' file
1
2 3 4 5 6
7
8
9
10
```

The second `%s` in the `printf` format specifier is replaced by either the Field Separator (a space by default) or the Record Separator (a newline) depending on whether the Record Number is within the range.

Alternatively:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(2<=NR&&NR<=5?FS:RS)}1' file
1
2 3 4 5 6
7
8
9
10
```

Change the Output Record Separator depending on the line number and print every line.

You can pass variables for the start and end if you want, using `awk -v start=2 -v end=5 '...'`

Comment: I've used second example & it's working which is most important tnx!

Comment: @josifoski a program that produces the expected output is the starting point for a solution. Consider how you'd enhance this script to do something trivial like printing the input line number before every output value (just change `printf "%s%s", $0,...` to `printf "%s %s%s", NR, $0,...` in that first example or change `1` to `{print NR, $0}` in that 2nd example). Now consider how you'd modify the sed solution you selected to do the same. sed is simply not the right tool for anything other than simple substitutions on a single line.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '20,500{N;s/^(.*)(\n)/\2\1 /;D}' file
```

or perhaps more readably:

```
sed ':a;20,500{N;s/\n/ /;ta}' file
```

Comment: Missing single quote at the end of the second example?

Comment: also missing \\( before braces, however, I've choosed this one only because sed is mentioned. Struggling myself to learn sed, or awk or perl. For now seding :)

Comment: @josifoski sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, it's useful commands are s, g, and p (with -n). All of it's other language constructs became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. I would strongly recommend you use the posted awk solution for this and any other problems that involve processing multiple lines of input simultaneously and don't bother trying to learn/use all of the other sed language constructs because the awk alternative is always more robust, portable, extensible, maintainable, clearer, usually faster and often briefer.

Comment: @ed-morton tnx for advice!

Comment: @josifoski You're welcome. Dont get me wrong, I use sed almost daily and it's great for what it's best at and I'm sure in the early 1970s when it was the only alternative to `ed` all of those constructs to do things with multiple lines were very useful but that was a LONG time ago! I'd recommend you get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you're going to be doing any but the most trivial text processing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perl version:

```
my $min = 5; my $max = 10;
while (<DATA>) {
    if ($. > $min && $. < $max) {
        chomp;
        $_ .= " ";
    }
    print;
}

__DATA__
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6 7 8 9 10
11
12
13
14
15
```

It reads in `DATA` (which you can set to being a filehandle or whatever your application requires), and checks the line number, `$.`. While the line number is between `$min` and `$max`, the line ending is `chomp`ed off and a space added to the end of the line; otherwise, the line is printed as-is.

Comment: `$_` is a "default" variable -- for a number of different functions, you don't need to specify a named variable (e.g. `$i`); you can use this default variable. If you do want to refer to it, you can use `$_`. In this case, `$_` is the current line of `__DATA__` that we're looking at. [More information in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables). `.=` means append to string; in this case, we're appending a space to the current line.